# Transpose Column vector to row vector

Tags: arrays, vba, transpose

I supposed to face with a simple task, but I finding some problems to transpose a 1D array/Column vector [0..n, 0..0] to a 1D array/Row vector [0..0, 0..n].

I tried using the Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose built-in function without success. It only seems to work with nD array/matrix.

The context is:
 - the 1D array/Column vector comes from a Recordset.GetRows method (if Recordset.Recordcount=1 => the array is a 1D array/Column vector)
 - the 1D array/Row vector (obtained by the transpose function) is used to populate the listbox.list property of a listbox object

Is there a smart way to transpose a 1D array (from Column vector to Row vector and viceversa) ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Transpose Zero-Based Arrays

- The problem with `Application.Transpose` is that it transposes a 1D
  **any**-based one-row array to a 2D **one**-based one-column array. Now when you try to transpose back you will end up with a 1D **one**-based one-row array (see `TransposeIssue`).
- **Toggle Transpose** will 'recognize' if the array is vertical or
  horizontal and will transpose accordingly (see `toggleTransposeTest`). It will accept **only** zero-based arrays.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Transposes a 1D zero-based (one-row) array                      '
'                       to a 2D zero-based one-column array and vice versa.    '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function toggleTranspose0(SourceArray As Variant) As Variant
    Dim Transpose, i As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    i = UBound(SourceArray, 2)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        If LBound(SourceArray) <> 0 Then Exit Function
        GoSub transposeVertical
    Else
        If i <> 0 Then Exit Function
        GoSub transposeHorizontal
    End If
    toggleTranspose0 = Transpose
Exit Function
transposeVertical:
    ReDim Transpose(UBound(SourceArray), 0)
    For i = 0 To UBound(SourceArray)
        Transpose(i, 0) = SourceArray(i)
    Next i
Return
transposeHorizontal:
    ReDim Transpose(UBound(SourceArray))
    For i = 0 To UBound(SourceArray)
        Transpose(i) = SourceArray(i, 0)
    Next i
Return
End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Sub toggleTransposeTest()
    Dim v, t, i As Long
    ReDim v(9)
    ' Populate data to 1D array.
    For i = 0 To 9
        v(i) = i + 1
    Next i
    ' Transpose to 2D zero-based one-column array.
    t = toggleTranspose0(v)
    For i = 0 To 9
        Debug.Print t(i, 0)
    Next i
    ' Transpose back to 1D array.
    v = toggleTranspose0(t)
    For i = 0 To 9
        Debug.Print v(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Sub TransposeIssue()
    Dim v, t, i As Long
    ReDim v(9)
    ' Populate data to 1D zero-based one-row array.
    For i = 0 To 9
        v(i) = i + 1
        Debug.Print i, v(i)
    Next i
    ' Convert 1D array to a 1D one-based one-row array.
    t = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(v))
    For i = 1 To 10
        Debug.Print i, t(i)
    Next
    ' Transpose to 2D one-based one-column array.
    t = Application.Transpose(v)
    For i = 1 To 10
        Debug.Print i, t(i, 1)
    Next
    ' Transpose to 1D one-based one-row array.
    v = Application.Transpose(t)
    For i = 1 To 10
        Debug.Print i, v(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting me in the right direction... I don't know if this behaviour is a bug or only a poor design, but manipulating your code I wrote an UDF function which manage all transpose scenarios (I hope :) )

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the code suggested by @VBasic2008, I post the UDF function I wrote to manage all transpose scenarios.

Features:

- any-based arrays management
- no modification of the base of input array at the exit from the UDF function
- 2 options for managing 1D (one-row) array/1D (one-column) array

```
Function Transpose(sAr As Variant, Optional Force2DOneRowArray As Boolean = True, Optional Force2DOneClmArray As Boolean = True) As Variant
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Transposes any-based array, manages in the right way the case of                  '
'               2D (one-row) array/1D array to a 2D (one-column) array and vice versa             '
' Arguments:                                                                                      '
' - sAr                Source Array                                                               '
' - Force2DOneRowArray Force function to transpose 2D matrix [n x 0]/1D (one-column) array to     '
'                      2D matrix [0 x n]/1D (one-row) array rather than to a simple 1D array      '
' - Force2DOneClmArray Force function to transpose 2D matrix [0 x n]/1D (one-row) array to        '
'                      2D matrix [n x 0]/1D (one-column) array rather than to a simple 1D array   '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim tAr As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    i = UBound(sAr, 2)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then                                 '1D (one-row) array --> Vertical transpose
        On Error GoTo 0
        ReDim tAr(LBound(sAr) To UBound(sAr), 0)
            For i = LBound(sAr) To UBound(sAr)
                tAr(i, 0) = sAr(i)
            Next i
    Else                                                    '2D array
        If i <> 0 Then
            If UBound(sAr) <> 0 Then                        '2D matrix [n x m]
                ReDim tAr(LBound(sAr, 2) To UBound(sAr, 2), LBound(sAr) To UBound(sAr))
                    For i = LBound(sAr, 2) To UBound(sAr, 2)
                        For j = LBound(sAr) To UBound(sAr)
                            tAr(i, j) = sAr(j, i)           '2D matrix [n x m] --> 2D matrix [m x n]
                        Next j
                    Next i
            Else                                            '2D matrix [0 x n]/1D (one-row) array --> Vertical transpose
                If Force2DOneClmArray Then
                    ReDim tAr(LBound(sAr, 2) To UBound(sAr, 2), 0)
                        For i = LBound(sAr, 2) To UBound(sAr, 2)
                            tAr(i, 0) = sAr(0, i)           '2D matrix [n x 0]/1D (one-column) array
                        Next i
                Else
                    ReDim tAr(LBound(sAr, 2) To UBound(sAr, 2))
                        For i = LBound(sAr, 2) To UBound(sAr, 2)
                            tAr(i) = sAr(0, i)              '1D array
                        Next i
                End If
            End If
        Else                                                '2D matrix [n x 0]/1D (one-column) array --> Horizontal transpose
            If Force2DOneRowArray Then
                ReDim tAr(0, LBound(sAr) To UBound(sAr))
                    For i = LBound(sAr) To UBound(sAr)
                        tAr(0, i) = sAr(i, 0)               '2D matrix [0 x n]/1D (one-row) array
                    Next i
            Else
                ReDim tAr(LBound(sAr) To UBound(sAr))
                    For i = LBound(sAr) To UBound(sAr)
                        tAr(i) = sAr(i, 0)                  '1D array
                    Next i
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Transpose = tAr
End Function
```